# Rails Paperclip content type validation by exclusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I am working on a messaging system for our internal use and each message can have attachments. Said attachments can be pretty much any type of file but there are some types of files that I don't want to allow, like for instance EXEs.

Instead of listing a huge amount of accepted content_types in the model's validation which is far from practical and will for sure block files that should be accepted, I would rather simply specify the content types that should **not** be accepted.

Googling around has yielded no results, but I'm sure someone else has come across this situation before, any idea of how to best tackle this?

Answer (score 3):

So this is what I ended up doing:

```
has_mongoid_attached_file :file

do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :file
validate :excluded_content_type

def excluded_content_type
  forbidden = [
    "application/x-msdownload",
    "application/x-ms-installer",
    "application/x-elf",
    "application/x-sh",
    "application/x-shellscript",
    "text/x-perl",
    "text/x-python",
    "application/javascript"
  ]
  errors.add(:base, 'Executable and script files are not allowed.') if forbidden.include? file_content_type
end
```

I don't know if this is the best way to do it but it works. If you have a better way of doing it post your answer!

Answer (score 2):

If **content types** that should **not be accepted**.

Write in model.rb

```
  has_attached_file :record_attachment      
  validates_attachment_content_type :record_attachment, presence: false, :content_type => {:not => "application/zip"}
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".